# How to set the distance between objects accurately?

Tags: measurement

[image]

I want to have the same distance between all objects.

Comment: use measureit addon

Comment: MeasureIt will only measure the distance, one way to make modeling a bit easier  is to use duplivertices. Model a circle of those forms like in the picture with vertices in the places you'd like rectangles to be. Then parent rectangle to circle and enable dupliverts. You can measure with the addon what you get.

Comment: I would suggest an array on a curve modifier

Comment: MeasureIt did help. Thank you for your support.